# travel comparison websites

Tags: web-services, web-scraping

Just wondering how the travel comparison websites work, and how does one go about making one?

by travel comparison websites I mean the websites that search other websites to find the different information about a particular flight and hotel and so on,

How can a website search another website?

any information would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: some larger sites may offer an API for developers to access their databases/services

Comment: Yes, most comparison sites don't really search other webpages, they partnership with businesses that upload their products and services either via an API on the price comparison site or just making their products available to them via RSS/XML or a simple CSV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some API's, take a look http://blog.programmableweb.com/2007/10/29/5-travel-apis-from-comparison-to-booking/